# Passing Stripe Fee to Customer: Unaccounted Profit with Formula Usage

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments

Referring to when you [pass the Stripe fee to your customer](https://support.stripe.com/questions/passing-the-stripe-fee-on-to-customers) by offsetting the final total charge to them using the given formula.

Considering the following scenario for a Payment Intent:

- Buyer is purchasing a $1,000.00 item (Pgoal)
- Buyer is charged Australian Stripe fees of 1.75% on the item (Fpercent)
- Buyer is charged a fixed fee of $0.30 AUD (Ffixed)
- Buyer is charged a 10% tax only on the Stripe fees component (Ftax, i.e. 10% of whatever is 1.75% of the amount + 30c fixed)

When I check Stripe Dashboard for this Payment Intent using the formula prescribed by Stripe, the following is calculated:

```
Amount: A$1,019.92
Fee: A$18.15
Stripe Processing Fees: A$16.50
Tax: A$1.65
Net: A$1,001.77
```

The problem is **why am I profiting $1.77**?? It should be **$1,000.00 flat**. Not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help is appreciated.

The formula Stripe provides is pretty straight forward:

```
Pcharge = ( Pgoal + Ffixed ) 
          ------------------
           ( 1 - Fpercent )

- Pgoal is $1,000.00 or 100000 (in cents)
- Ffixed is 0.30 or 30 (in cents)
- Fpercent is 1.75% or 0.0175
```

The only issue with above formula is that it doesn't account for Stripe's taxes it charges the Buyer, which in Australia is 10% on the total Stripe fees. So I've gone ahead and accounted for it in the numerator of the formula:

```
Pcharge = ( Pgoal + Ffixed + Ftax ) 
          -------------------------
               ( 1 - Fpercent )

- Pgoal is $1,000.00 or 100000 (in cents)
- Ffixed is 0.30 or 30 (in cents)
- Fpercent is 1.75% or 0.0175
- Ftax is 10% on the Stripe fees, or [ 0.1 * ( Pgoal * Fpercent + Ffixed ) ]
```